# Dynamic allocation and displaying

Tags: c++

I have a Problem in displaying the outputs E.G when i enter **Salim Oman  88.4**
the function displays only the first letter in name and country i.e **S  O  88.4** and i want to dispaly the whole name

**// Here is the Display()function**

```
void Display(char ** Names, char ** countries, float * Grades, int num_names)
{
int i;
 for (i=0;i<num_names;i++)
 {
    cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
    cout<<** Names<<"\t"<<** countries<<"\t"<<* Grades<<endl;
 }
}
```

**i used GetName() to read the data entered by the user**

```
void GetName(char name[], char country[], float & grade)
{
cout<<"Enter name: ";
cin>>name;
cout<<"Enter country: ";
cin>>country;
cout<<"Enter grade: ";
cin>>grade;
}
```

**// AddName()function allocates new array of pointers and copy prvious data to these arrays**

```
void AddName(char **& Names, char **& Countries, float *& Grades, int & num_names)
{
char name[ MAXSIZE], country[ MAXSIZE];
float grade=0;
int i;
GetName(name,country,grade); // call 
//creat an array of character pointers
Names = new char * [num_names];
countries = new char * [num_names];
//creat an array of float
Grades = new float  [num_names];

for(i=0;i<num_names;i++)
{
    Names[i]= new char [strlen(name)+1]; //Allocate room for the enterd name
    strcpy(Names[i],name);//Copy the name to the nwely allocated space 
    countries[i] = new char [strlen(country)+1]; //Allocate room for the enterd name
    strcpy(countries[i],country);//Copy the country to the nwely allocated space 
    Grades[i]=grade;// Copy the grade to the Grades
}
++num_names; // increment the number of names to add another name 

}
```

Comment: Is this a school project?....

Comment: What exactly is your question? [Other than "do my homework"?]

Comment: Read the question well first and then judge , i am not asking you to write the code for me, i posted the code and i asked for a problem faced me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout<<** Names<<"\t"<<** countries<<"\t"<<* Grades<<endl;
```

should be

```
cout<<Names[i]<<"\t"<<countries[i]<<"\t"<<Grades[i]<<endl;
```

`Names`, `countries` and `Grades` are arrays. If you want to access the nth element of an array you do it like this `array[n]` not `**array` or `*array`.